# Error is C# DateTime.Now returns persian date

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

DateTime.Now in C# must return '11/30/2019 11:10:12 AM' but it returns '09/09/1398 11:10:12 ق.ظ'
in Asp.Net web Applications i have this problem, but in C# console application does not any problem.

```
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post your [MCVE] as a plain text? Imgur was blocked in Turkey, so..

Comment: DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now;

Comment: Please pay attention that this problem is just for c# web applications but it returns correct date time in Gregorian format.

Comment: @yaghobabbasi Did you check the linked question? A DateTime doesn't have a culture. Your problem emerges only (and correct me if I'm wrong) when you try to _display_ the DateTime value. Does `DateTime.Now.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` not solve this problem?

Comment: You could take a look at Nodatime https://nodatime.org/ or nuget package directly https://www.nuget.org/packages/NodaTime. No more time zone issues.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `DateTime` type itself is *always* in the Gregorian calendar, in terms of the values returned by `Year`, `Month` and `Day`.

What you're observing is the result of *formatting* the `DateTime`, which converts it in to the default calendar system for the default thread culture. The simplest way to fix this is to use the invariant culture:

```cs
using System;
using System.Globalization;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var dateTime = DateTime.Now;
        string formatted = dateTime.ToString(
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        Console.WriteLine(formatted); // 2019-11-30 09:19:43 or similar
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this work for me. is there any way to correct this problem on windows server 2016?

Comment: @yaghobabbasi: That code should work fine on Windows Server 2016. I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: It does not convert DateTime in a view, I have: value="@(Model.Date.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))" in an input text, But it does not return a gregorian date! also I tried {Model.Date.Value.Year}-... when I hover over Date or Value it shows correct english date but when I hover on year, that is something else. I tried both .Net Framework MVC and MVC core 7 that are the same. is there any solution for this?

Comment: @mz1378: Please create a new question with a [mcve] - it sounds like you've got a problem with how you're obtaining the DateTime to start with.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this to force it to return `DateTime` with the standard US culture info.

```
CultureInfo MyCultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
DateTime MyNewDate = DateTime.Parse(DateTime.Now.ToString(), MyCultureInfo);
```

Comment: Many thanks for your response but when i run your code i got this error:                 
{"The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 20."}    because DateTime.Now return '09/09/1398 11:10:12 ق.ظ'